# this.Master.Page.FindControl("iwMenuMain") returns null. Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have login form (iwFormLogin), based on master page, which contains ASPxMenu menu with id "iwMenuMain". Why does this.Master.Page.FindControl("iwMenuMain") returns null?
C# method:

```
private void iwUpdateMenu()
{
    ASPxMenu menuMain = null;

    try
    {
        menuMain = this.Master.Page.FindControl(iwConstants.iwFrmRoot.iwMenuMainID) as ASPxMenu;
        // menuMain is null after upper statement. Why?!

        this.iwDataSourceMenus.SelectParameters.Clear();
        this.iwDataSourceMenus.SelectParameters.Add(@"cUserId",
            this.iwTextBoxUsername.Text.ToString());
        this.iwDataSourceMenus.SelectParameters.Add(@"cProgramId",
            this.iwComboBoxAvailablePrograms.SelectedItem.Value.ToString());
        this.iwDataSourceMenus.SelectParameters.Add(@"bDebug",
            "1");

        DataView dv = (DataView)this.iwDataSourceMenus.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
        if((menuMain != null) || (dv != null))
        {
            menuMain.DataSource = dv;
            menuMain.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        menuMain.Visible = false;
    }   // try
```

And here is Master page menu declaration:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Root.master.cs" Inherits="iwDashboard.Root" %>
<%@ Register assembly="DevExpress.Web.v13.2, Version=13.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors" tagprefix="dx" %>
<%@ Register assembly="DevExpress.Web.v13.2, Version=13.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxCallbackPanel" tagprefix="dx" %>
<%@ Register assembly="DevExpress.Web.v13.2, Version=13.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxPanel" tagprefix="dx" %>
<%@ Register assembly="DevExpress.Web.v13.2, Version=13.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxMenu" tagprefix="dx" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Styles/Site.css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder
        ID="head"
        runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form
        id="FormMain"
        runat="server">    
    <div class="headerContainer" >
        <table
            style="width:100%;text-align:right;">
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:right;">
                    <dx:ASPxLabel
                        ID="iwLabelThemes"
                        runat="server"
                        ForeColor="White"
                        AssociatedControlID="iwLabelThemes"
                        Text="Themes:">
                    </dx:ASPxLabel>
                </td>
                <td style="width:150px;text-align:left;">
                    <dx:ASPxComboBox
                        ID="iwComboBoxThemes"
                        Theme="Moderno"
                        runat="server"
                        AssociatedControlID="iwComboBoxThemes" AutoPostBack="True">
                        <ClientSideEvents SelectedIndexChanged="function(s, e)
                            {
                                ASPxClientUtils.SetCookie(&quot;wiThemeSelected&quot;,
                                    s.GetValue());
                            }"/>
                    </dx:ASPxComboBox>                
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div
        class="menuContainer">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <dx:ASPxMenu
                ID="iwMenuMain"
                runat="server"
                CssClass="mainMenu"
                VerticalAlign="Middle"
                Visible="false">
            </dx:ASPxMenu>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder
            ID="iwContentPlaceholderMain"
            runat="server">       
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the value of this constant? iwConstants.iwFrmRoot.iwMenuMainID

Comment: public static class iwFrmRoot
    {
        public static string iwFrmID = @"FormMain";
        public static string iwMenuMainID = @"iwMenuMain";
    }

Comment: Controls cannot be found directly that way. They are structured in a hierarchy and you have to go through it with recursivity or providing a path.

Comment: Gonzix, thanks, can you provide me with some example?

Comment: @Gonzix: of course you can, you just need recursivity if the control you're looking for is not in the `NamingContainer` of the control that you're using with `FindControl`. In this case it should work since no controls implement `INamingContainer`. The problem is that OP is using `Master.Page.FindControl` instead of `Master.FindControl`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter right, I didn't notice that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are accessing a control that is declared directly under the master page, do the following instead...

```
this.Master.FindControl("iwMenuMain")
```

You do NOT need to do a fully-recursive search to find this control given the control hierarchy you have defined in your master page. You would, if it were nested within another control

Answer (score 1):

You are looking in the `Page` but it's in the `Master`, so replace

```
this.Master.Page.FindControl
```

with

```
this.Master.FindControl
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also Achieve your task By doing Following thing

```
Control div = this.Page.Master.FindControl("iwMenuMain");
```